# 3 joins and where clause together

Tags: sql, database

I have 3 tables

```
bl_main (bl_id UNIQUE, bl_area)
bl_details (bl_id UNIQUE, name) 
bl_data(bl_id, month, paper_tons, bottles_tons)
```

`bl_id` is not unique in the last table. There will be multiple rows of same `bl_id`.

I am trying to retrieve data in the following way

```
bl_id | name | bl_area | sum(paper_tons) | sum (bottles_tons) | paper_tons | bottles_tons
```

`sum(paper_tons)` should return the sum of all the paper tons for the same `bl_id` like Jan to December.

Using the below query i am able to retrieve all the data correctly except in the result, there are multiple occurances of `bl_ids(From bl_data table)`.

```
SELECT bl_main.bl_id,name,bl_area,sums.SummedPaper, sums.SummedBottles,paper_tons,bottles_tons
FROM bl_main
JOIN bl_details ON 
    bl_main.bl_id= bl_details.bl_id
left outer JOIN bl_data ON
    bl_data.bl_id= bl_main.bl_id
left outer JOIN (
    SELECT bl_id, SUM(Paper_tons) As SummedPaper, SUM(bottle_tons) As SummedBottles 
FROM bl_data
```

GROUP by bl_id) sums ON     sums.bl_id = bl_main.bl_id

I wanto retrieve only the unique values of bl_ids without repetition and it should contain the bl_id which has the max month and not all the months for the same bl_id.

For ex:

```
INCORRECT


**0601**    University Hall     75.76   17051   1356    4040    1154    **11**     
**0601**    University Hall     75.76   17051   1356    9190    101     **12**  
**0605**    UIC Student     22.86   3331    14799   0   356   **8**   

CORRECT   
**0601**    University Hall     75.76   17051   1356    9190    101     **12**  
**0605**    UIC Student     22.86   3331    14799   0   356   **8**
```

I know I can get the max value using

```
WHERE Month = (SELECT MAX(Month)
```

but where exactlt should i add this in the query and should i change the join definition. 
Any help is highly appreciated as i am new to sql. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Proofread your post and get your bl_id and bu_ids straight.

Comment: Based on the fact that he's writing raw queries, I wouldn't think he's using RDBMS

Comment: Does your query really run? I don't see any GROUP BY in the sub-query of last JOIN

Comment: @Quassnoi - Sql
@ Ic - done
@David - mysteriously it disappeared. But i have edited it now. and yes the query runs just fine

Answer (score 1):

You have two tables that probably should be combined into one (`bl_main` and `bl_details`). But putting that aside, what you need is a self-join subquery to select the row with the max month. Something like the following (untested):

```
SELECT bl_main.bl_id, bl_details.name, bl_main.bl_area, sums.sum_paper_tons,
       sums.sum_bottles_tons, maxmonth.paper_tons, maxmonth.bottles_tons
FROM bl_main
INNER JOIN bl_details ON bl_main.bl_id = bl_details.bl_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT bl_id, SUM(paper_tons) AS sum_paper_tons, 
                        SUM(bottles_tons) AS sum_bottles_tons
                 FROM bl_data
                 GROUP BY bl_id) sums ON bl_main.bl_id = sums.bl_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT bl_id, paper_tons, bottles_tons
                 FROM bl_data data2
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT bl_id, MAX(month) AS max_month
                             FROM bl_data
                             GROUP BY bl_id) m
                    ON m.bl_id = data2.bl_id
                    AND m.max_month = data2.month) maxmonth
    ON bl_main.bl_id = maxmonth.bl_id
```

Comment: Thanks Ic. I am trying really hard but i am unable to run the query. It gives an error - "column ambiguously defined". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could be the column aliases having the same name as the column they aggregate? I thought it could differentiate, but maybe not...

Comment: nope. Dint help. It still gives the error "column ambiguously defined". 
Thanks once again for your time. What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: This is what is breaking the query("column ambiguously defined")  

SELECT bl_id, paper_tons, bottles_tons                 FROM bl_data data2                 INNER JOIN (SELECT bl_id, MAX(month) AS max_month                             FROM bl_data                             GROUP BY bl_id   

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Got it. Thank a lot. It should be actually SELECT data2.bl_id, data2 .paper_tons, data2 .bottles_tons from .... and it works fine

Comment: @faffy Glad it worked. Too bad it didn't give a more specific error message but I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table containing the month against itself, using a subquery of the form:

```
Select *
From mytable m
    Inner Join (Select max(Month) as Month, myId
                From mytable
                Group By myId) mnth
        On mnth.myId = m.myId and mnth.Month = m.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN clause

```
left outer JOIN bl_data ON
  bl_data.bl_id= bl_main.bl_id
```

does not specify which month to select for the data you are displaying with paper_tons and bottles_tons.

You could update that JOIN to only contain the max month, and this should limit the entries, like so:

```
left outer JOIN (SELECT bl_id, MAX(Month) as Month from bl_data GROUP BY bl_id) as Month
  ON Month.bl_id = bl_main.bl_id
left outer JOIN bl_data ON
  bl_data.bl_id = bl_main.bl_id AND bl_data.Month = Month.bl_Month
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query is what you are looking for

```
SELECT bl_main.bl_id,name, bl_area, sums.SummedPaper, sums.SummedBottles, paper_tons, bottles_tons
FROM bl_main
    JOIN bl_details ON bl_main.bl_id= bl_details.bl_id
    left outer JOIN bl_data ON    bl_data.bl_id= bl_main.bl_id
    left outer JOIN
    (
        SELECT bl_id, month, SUM(Paper_tons) As SummedPaper, SUM(bottle_tons) As SummedBottles 
        FROM bl_data
        WHERE month in
        (SELECT MAX(month) FROM bl_data GROUP BY bl_id)
        GROUP BY bl_id, month
    ) sums ON sums.bl_id = bl_main.bl_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to just add a comment to the answer lc gave, but I don't have 50 reputation points yet. It is a link to an article that I believe explains this question and adds the why the solution that lc gave is correct.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-with-distinct-aggregates-and-derived-tables